# building makefile project with multiple .c files

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following project structure (using eclipse)

```
project/
 |____ inc/
 |       |___ config_prog.h
 |       |___ prog_lib.h
 |
 |____ data/
 |       |___ img.bmp
 |
 |__ prog_lib.c
 |__ main.c
 |__ makefile
```

And i made the following makefile :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -O0 -c -Wall -mavx2 -mfma
LDFLAGS=

SOURCES=$ main.c inc/prog_lib.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

EXECUTABLE=main

all: $(TASKMAP) $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ -lm

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -lm -o $@

clean: 
    rm -fr $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

but when i try to build the project i get the following error:`make: *** No rule to make target 'inc/prog_lib.c', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

Could someone tell me the problem?

Comment: The problem is `SOURCES=$ main.c inc/prog_lib.c`, which ought to be `SOURCES=$ main.c prog_lib.c`.

Comment: ...And you'll probably have a problem finding the header files until you pass `-Iinc` to the compiler, *as I'm sure you discovered when you tried building these files from the command line.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and take time to read its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Your variable assignment

```
 SOURCES=$ main.c inc/prog_lib.c
```

is wrong. It should be

```
 SOURCES= main.c prog_lib.c
```

You probably need also (better ask for `-g` to facilitate [debugging with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/))

```
CFLAGS= -O0 -c -Wall -g -mavx2 -mfma -Iinc
```

Try also `make -p` to understand the builtin rules. You should use them better (and then using `-c` in your `CFLAGS` is probably wrong).

Consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), perhaps as `remake -x`, to debug your `Makefile`; or at least `make --trace`.

BTW, I believe that your file hierarchy is too complex and inappropriate. For such a simple and small project, having an `inc/` directory is not worth the pain.

For inspiration, study the `Makefile` of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), e.g. on [github](http://github.com/).

Comment: Thank you now it works just fine .... and i took your advice regarding the project structure.