# Makefile in C (ubuntu) multiple definition

Tags: c, makefile

I am learning c and trying to build using makefile. I am stuck on the following error and don't know what to do next.

the build command is 
`gcc -o logfind logfind.o cmdargutils.o filesystem_utils.o file_utils.o strutils.o`

If I need both file_utils.o and cmdargutils.o but if I add both I get the following error.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro3uI.png)

**ERROR**

```
file_utils.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `MAX_LINE'
logfind.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'logfind' failed
make: *** [logfind] Error 1
```

The source is: 
**Makefile**

```
logfind: clean logfind.o
    gcc -o logfind logfind.o cmdargutils.o filesystem_utils.o file_utils.o strutils.o

logfind.o: logfind.c cmdargutils.o file_utils.o filesystem_utils.o strutils.o error_codes.h
    gcc -c logfind.c

cmdargutils.o: cmdargutils.c cmdargutils.h
    gcc -c cmdargutils.c

file_utils.o: file_utils.c file_utils.h
    gcc -c file_utils.c

filesystem_utils.o: filesystem_utils.c filesystem_utils.h
    gcc -c filesystem_utils.c

strutils.o: strutils.c strutils.h
    gcc -c strutils.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o logfind
```

**cmdargutils.h**

```
#ifndef CMD_ARG_UTILS
#define CMD_ARG_UTILS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "error_codes.h"
#include "strutils.h"

struct Argument {
    bool is_and_operation;
    int count;
    char **search_terms;
};

struct Argument *argument_create(int argc, char **argv, int start, bool is_and_operation);
void argument_destroy(struct Argument *argument);
struct Argument *parse_arguments(int argc, char **argv);

#endif
```

**error_codes.h**

```
#ifndef ERROR_CODES
#define ERROR_CODES

enum error_codes {
    MEMORY_ERROR,
    INPUT_ERROR
};

#endif
```

**file_utils.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_UTILS
#define FILE_UTILS

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cmdargutils.h"

const size_t MAX_LINE = 1024;

bool is_match(char *, struct Argument *); 
bool scan_file(char *, struct Argument *);

#endif
```

**filesystem_utils.h**

```
#ifndef FILESYSTEM_UTILS
#define FILESYSTEM_UTILS

#include <glob.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "strutils.h"

struct SearchFiles {
    int count;
    char **paths;
};

struct SearchFiles *search_files_create(int count, char** paths);
void search_files_destroy(struct SearchFiles *search_files);
struct SearchFiles *scan_directory(char *directory_path, char *pattern);

#endif
```

**strutils.h**

```
#ifndef STRUTILS
#define STRUTILS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "error_codes.h"

char *strdup(const char *source);
char **copy_string_array(char **source, int start, int end);

#endif
```

**logfind.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include "cmdargutils.h"
#include "filesystem_utils.h"
#include "file_utils.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct Argument *argument = parse_arguments(argc, argv);
    int i = 0;

    struct SearchFiles *search_files = scan_directory(".", "*.*");
    for(i = 0; i < search_files->count; i++) {
        scan_file(search_files->paths[i], argument);
    }

    search_files_destroy(search_files);
    argument_destroy(argument);
    return 0;    
}
```

**cmdargutils.c**

```
#include "cmdargutils.h"

struct Argument *argument_create(int argc, char **argv, int start, bool is_and_operation){
    struct Argument *argument = (struct Argument *)malloc(sizeof(struct Argument));

    if(!argument) {
        printf("Could not initialize arguments.\n"); 
        exit(MEMORY_ERROR);
    }
    argument->count =  argc - start;
    argument->is_and_operation = is_and_operation;
    argument->search_terms = copy_string_array(argv, start, argc);

    return argument; 
}

void argument_destroy(struct Argument *argument){
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < argument->count; i++) {
        free(argument->search_terms[i]);
    }

    free(argument->search_terms); 
    free(argument);
    argument = NULL;    
}

struct Argument *parse_arguments(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct Argument *argument = NULL;
    bool is_and_operation = true;
    int start = 0;

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        exit(INPUT_ERROR);
    }

    char *operation = argv[1];
    if(strcmp(operation, "-o") == 0) {
        is_and_operation = false;

        if(argc < 3) {
            printf("Not enough arguments\n");
            exit(INPUT_ERROR);
        }
    }

    start = is_and_operation ? 1 : 2;

    argument = argument_create(argc, argv, start, is_and_operation); 

    return argument;
}
```

**file_utils.c**

```
#include "file_utils.h"

bool is_match(char *line, struct Argument *argument) {
    int i = 0;
    bool isMatch = false;
    for(i = 0; i < argument->count; i++) {
        char *found = strcasestr(line, argument->search_terms[i]);
        if(!found) {
            if(argument->is_and_operation) {
                isMatch = false;
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            isMatch = true;
            if(argument->is_and_operation) {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isMatch;
}

bool scan_file(char *path, struct Argument *argument) {
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");

    int line_number = 0;
    char *line = malloc(MAX_LINE);

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE - 1, file)!= NULL) {
        ++line_number;
        if(is_match(line, argument)) {
            printf("%s:%d\n", path, line_number);
            printf("\t%s\n", line);
        }
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(file);
}
```

**filesystem_utils.c**

```
#include "filesystem_utils.h"

struct SearchFiles *search_files_create(int count, char** paths) {
    struct SearchFiles *search_files = (struct SearchFiles *)malloc(sizeof(struct SearchFiles));

    search_files->count = count;
    search_files->paths = copy_string_array(paths, 0, count); 

    return search_files;    
}

void search_files_destroy(struct SearchFiles *search_files) {
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < search_files->count; i++) {
        free(search_files->paths[i]);    
    }

    free(search_files->paths);
    free(search_files);
    search_files = NULL;
}

struct SearchFiles *scan_directory(char *directory_path, char *pattern) {
    glob_t globbuf;
    int error = glob(pattern, GLOB_MARK, NULL, &globbuf);

    if(!error) {
        struct SearchFiles *search_files = search_files_create(globbuf.gl_pathc, globbuf.gl_pathv);
        globfree(&globbuf);
        return search_files;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**strutils.c**

```
#include "strutils.h"

char *strdup(const char *source) {
    char *dest = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);
    if(!dest) {
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        exit(MEMORY_ERROR);
    }
    strcpy(dest, source);
    return dest;
}

char **copy_string_array(char **source, int start, int end) {
    char **dest = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (end - start));
    int di = 0;
    int si = start;

    for(di = 0, si = start; si < end; 
        si++, di++) {
        dest[di] = strdup(source[si]);        
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Your `Makefile` is bad because it does not take advantage of builtin rules (obtained by  `make -p`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50317752/841108) answer.

Comment: You really should spend a few days reading more.

Comment: Don't put screenshots in your question, copy & paste the error message.

Comment: You should read a lot more and improve your coding habits. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### read documentation!

First, take a few hours to read documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), and read how to [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You also need to understand more about the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), so read [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). You want to take advantage of builtin GNU `make` rules (so run `make -p` to understand them) and variables. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311517/841108) answer. You could use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (as `remake -x`) to debug your `Makefile`. You apparently don't understand how `make` and how `gcc` should be used, so you need to read more. Read also a [C tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/), look into some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and glance when needed into the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Of course, read the documentation of *every* function you use (e.g. [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) etc..). For Linux system programming, read a book like [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and relevant `man` pages from [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html) etc...

Then read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You certainly want to compile with all warnings and debug info.

---

### a better `Makefile`

You might try something like:

```
# a better Makefile
# your C compiler
CC= gcc

# the verbose remove
RM= rm -vf

# your C compilation flags
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -g

# your C source files
MY_CSOURCES= logfind.c cmdargutils.c filesystem_utils.c file_utils.c strutils.c

# the corresponding object files
MY_OBJECTS= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(MY_CSOURCES))

# the conventional phony targets
.PHONY: all clean

# the only program is for the default target all
all: logfind
logfind: $(MY_OBJECTS)
     $(LINK.c) $< -o $@

# cleaning the mess
clean: 
     $(RM) logfind *.o *~
```

Of course, you need dependencies for object files on header files. You could compute them automatically, but it is simpler to explicit them, so add something like:

```
strutils.o: strutils.c strutils.h
```

and so on for each other object files.

BTW my [HelloWorld/](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/tree/master/HelloWorld) directory on github is a tutorial example for using `make`

---

### your *multiple definition* bug

You are getting `multiple definition of MAX_LINE` because it is *defined* in a header file included by several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), hence several translation units define it.

So either make it a preprocessor constant `#define MAX_LINE 1024` in your header `file_utils.h`, or put there only a *declaration* like `extern const int MAX_LINE;` and *define* it only once in a single translation unit, as `const int MAX_LINE=1024;` in `file_utils.c`

---

### general hints

I strongly recommend doing some [iterative and incremental development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development): code only one or two dozen lines at once, then compile them, improve them to get no warnings, debug them with the [GDB debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and test them. At last repeat all this till satisfied. I do recommend using also a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (like [git](https://git-scm.com/)) even for school homework.

You might want to use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and other [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) bugs.

You could also use some static source analyzer like [clang-analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or even [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/).

Once your program is debugged, you might add [optimization flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) like `-O2` into your `CFLAGS` (in particular if you benchmark it with [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)).

You could be interested by [ntfw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. An additional question, if you don't mind: I am learning c through "Learn C the hard way book". It's pretty good and requires a lot of search over internet to learn concepts which the author encourages. I would like to ask you what would be a better way to learn C. My target being learning the Linux System and ultimately try Kernel Programming ?

Comment: Read http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight (you'll need many *years* of work). BTW, I recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), it is an excellent introduction to programming (and you want to become a developer, not just a C coder)